# How to unload RVM from current shell?

Tags: ruby, rvm

How can I unload RVM from the current shell? I found [this](https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/1425), but I'm not sure how to use it. It is nowhere documented.

Comment: Does running `__rvm_unload` in the shell not work for you?

Comment: That's the answer to my problem. Thank you, I didn't know what command to use.

Comment: Great! I'll add it as an answer.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`__rvm_unload` is a shell function, which can be run like a normal command:

```
$ __rvm_unload
```